# Hadoop Transparent Data Encryption: protection from interference of EDEK, EZK and DEK

Tags: encryption, audit

I am preparing a response to a security auditor. They have presented a generic question about the protection from substitution of KEK and DEK in a "normal" encryption mechanism.

What protection exists with Hadoop TDE for the equivalent EDEK and EZK?